# How to map dataroot to Azure Storage in Moodle

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, moodle

Deployed Moodle into Azure Web Apps. Created an Azure Storage account and a container, linked the web app to the Azure Storage account and now have a connection string in place, something like `

> CUSTOMCONNSTR_MS_StorAccConStr =
>   DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=prefix/longkey+someverylongkey/suffix==

How to map the dataroot location to Azure Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Moodle_site_moodle_directory](https://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Moodle_site_moodle_directory) mentioned about **moodledata** folder:

> "moodledata" is a folder that contains user files, course files, site language, cached and other information. It is created in the Moodle install process. It should be located outside of the "moodle" folder and is called by default "moodledata".

Also, as this [discuss](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=328634) in moodle forum about `dataroot` folder:

> Dataroot is a folder (aka directory) not a file, many files are stored within it. When setting your dataroot in your config.php this should be a reference to **a file-system location** that the webserver can read and write to, **you simply cannot do this over HTTP**.

Per my understanding, you could host Moodle on Azure VM and mount [Azure File Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files) from the Azure VM that hosts the moodle website, then you could leverage the mounted file share as the `dataroot`.

Here are some tutorials, you could refer to them:

**1.Install Moodle on Azure VM**

Access [bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/moodle/cloud/azure) to launch a free demo Moodle hosted on Azure VM. Or log into Azure Portal, input the keyword "moodle" under "Marketplace > Everything" blade, choose the Moodle and create it as follows:

[image]

**2.Create your file share and mount it from your VM**

[Mount the file share from an Azure virtual machine running Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share)

[Mount the file share from an Azure virtual machine running Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-how-to-use-files-linux#mount-the-file-share)

**3.Change dataroot location**

https://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Creating_Moodle_site_data_directory

Comment: i think we ought to create a plugin similar to the one created for WordPress. that should make it easier for Web App deployments.